# Использование комментариев в виде отзывов

Tags: wordpress

Есть надобность реализовать функционал оставления отзывов на сайте у клиента. Сам блок отзывов выводится в виде слайдера с именем, текстом отзыва и датой.

Толковых плагинов для данной задачи я не нашел. Вернее не нашел тех, которые позволяют модифицировать вид выводимой записи.

Решил это реализовать посредством обычных комментариев. Но столкнулся со следующей проблемой, а именно как сказать форме отправки что комментарии надо оставлять для такой то записи.

Комментарии на сайте больше негде не используются, так что я решил все сделать следующим способом:

- на сайте есть всплывающее окно с формой для комментирования.
- в нужном месте на сайте подключена страница, для которой собственно и оставляются комментарии

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это не вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уж Вы хотите делать это посредством комментариев, предлагаю создать страницу "оставить отзыв". Там будет форма для комментариев. Сами комментарии скройте. 
После того, в том месте, где вы хотите вывести отзывы, вы вытягиваете комментарии страницы "оставить отзыв".

Answer (score 0):

Присмотритесь к тому, как это реализовано на StackOverflow:

- У каждого вопроса и ответа (т.е. у всего, что можно комментировать), есть свой id
- У каждого комментируемого сообщения есть своя кнопка, чтобы добавить комментарий именно к нему. На каком сообщении ткнули кнопку - к тому и комментарий.
- У каждого комментария есть свой id. Всё это позволяет связывать комментарии с сообщениями в базе данных.